# FSCalendar particular month and date showing in weekView - Swift

Tags: swift3, fscalendar

I have two ViewControllers A & B Both VC have calendarView (week View).B VC I selected particular date in month of August When I back to A VC that particular date is selected but in UI its shows today date and current week while swiping only I can get selected date.How to show selected date week show in Week View?

Answer (score 0):

FSCalendarView.currentPage = SELECTEDDATE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).